# Make sure that submit function is firing on certain button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

I have a submit function:

```
jQ("webform-client-form-' . $form['#node']->nid . '").submit(function(event) 
  var curElement = document.activeElement;
  console.log(curElement);
  var $btn = curElement.attr("class");
  $webform = $btn.split(\' \')[0];
  console.log($webform);
  if($webform == "webform-submit") {
    console.log("yeahah");
  }

  var $form = jQ(this);
  if ($form.find("[data-stripe=\"token\"]").attr("value") == "") {
    $form.find("button").prop("disabled", true)
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
  }
 else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

and try do fire that function only on pressing a certain button. Problem is that when pressing the button, `document.activeElement` is the `<html>` tag and not the button I pressed. Does anyone know if I did something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: instead of document.activeElement do jQ(this). You are using jQuery so why not use it.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble if I do jQ(this) it throws me the form as object, not the button!